# Android to CodeIgniter how to receive chunk data

Tags: android, web, compression

Currently Using:

- Android: Api Level 19
- CodeIgniter
- EasyPHP

**My Problem:**

I have a JSON data , What I want to do is GZIP it and send it to my web API which is run by codeigniter and chunks its data. My web API works well when I just sent JSON data but as I send GZIP data then chunk it I can't even receive the data from my web API or was it supposed to be because of my network.

What is the core development of the project is that in mobile application it gathers information , I think it is quite big because it actually measures up to 10 megabytes which is a downsize to the whole process. When sending this to my server which is not good for the end users side, now I want it JSON data to be GZIP then I want the sending of these data to be chunked so that it would feel a lot faster and optimized as before.

**Android Code:**

```
    private void addTaskInThreadPool(final ClassEntry entry) {

      try {
          List<NameValuePair> pairs = new ArrayList<NameValuePair>();
          String s = "{\"entry\":" + gson.toJson(entry) + "}";
          pairs.add(new BasicNameValuePair("token", user.token));
          pairs.add(new BasicNameValuePair("data", s));
          threadPool.addTask(new ClientPostRequest.Builder(ClassSend.this,
                  GeneralResponse.class,Utils.getbaseUrl(ClassSend.this) + "survey/submit_entry/",
                pairs) {

                  @Override
                  public Object doInBackground(Object result) { 
                        return result;                              
                  }

                  @Override
                  public void onPostExecute(Object result) {
                        
                  }
        
           }.showProgressBar(false).showToast(true).build());

      } catch(ClassCastException e) {
          Log.e("threadBackGround ClassCast", "Error: " + e);
      }
   }
```

Can somebody help me? I need this for my project and research. I need your suggestions , critics , I would highly appreciate this to upgrade my programming skills I'm still a newbie for this one I need my fellow SO mates to help me with my problem.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Just Added this code in my method AddTaskInThreadPool

```
        String s = "{\"entry\":" + gson.toJson(unsyncedEntry) + "}";
        StringEntity entityForPost = new StringEntity(s);
        ByteArrayOutputStream baos = new ByteArrayOutputStream();

        try (GZIPOutputStream gzos = new GZIPOutputStream(baos)) {
            gzos.write(entityForPost.toString().getBytes("UTF8"));
            gzos.close();
        } catch (IOException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }

        byte[] fooGzippedBytes = baos.toByteArray();
        String encodeBytes = Base64.encode(fooGzippedBytes);
        pairs.add(new BasicNameValuePair("token", user.token));
        pairs.add(new BasicNameValuePair("data", s));
```

and it works.